# How to load json dynamically in ReactJS component?

Tags: reactjs

The URL is dynamic

`url/:id/:name` (using Reach Router)

```
url/1/name1  
url/2/differnet-link  
url/3/another-link
```

In Article Component, I want to load `1.json` if the URL is `url/1/name1` or `2.json` if the URL ID is 2

```
import menuArray from '../data/menu.json';
```

This is how I usually load JSON in ReactJS

```
class Article extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) { 
       super(props);
       if(/* id is available in the menuArray */) {
          // I want to load the JSON by id and store it in state
       }  
    } 
}
```

What is the optimal solution to load dynamic JSON file in ReactJS?

Comment: According to Reach Router docs the url params should be available as props? so in theory you should have a props.id available inside your Article?

Comment: yes. I can get the id from props. But how to import json inside a constructor?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this is of any use but I recently built a site where I had to dynamically load markdown files for content in the page based on a prop:

```
const getMarkdown = async (page) => {
  const markdownFilePath = `./content/${page}.md`
  const markdownFile = await require(`${markdownFilePath}`)
  return markdownFile
}
```

then in my component I would do:

```
const introText = getMarkdown(page)
```

and then render `{introText}`

You could do the same thing with an async require with your json file using the id from your url params?

Comment: I think this is what i want. I will share my comment after finishing the job.

Comment: Hi @Mahesh just wondering if this worked out for you in the end?

Answer (score -3):

A better way is to create a .js file and then use const e.g: data.js

```
const navigation = [
    {
        navItemId: 1,
        navItemName: 'About Me',
        navItemPath: '/'
    }
];
export {navigation};
```

The file where you want to use it, use the below code:

```
import { navigation, bio, education } from './constants';
state = {navigation: navigation}
```