# How to load json/xml files for use with tensorflow?

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow

I have a json and xml file located in the model folder that I would like to load from StreamScreen.js:

```
Website
|-public
|-src
    |-components
        |-StreamScreen.js
    |-model
        |-model.json
        |-haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
```

But no matter what I do, this file doesn't get loaded. I can load images from the model folder just fine, but not this json or xml.

```
const modelFile = require("../model/model.json")
...
const faceCascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier();
const faceCascadeFile = require("../model/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
faceCascade.load(faceCascadeFile);
...
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelFile);
```

The require function is returning a filepath for the xml/json, but the xml and json aren't located in the local files. [Screenshots here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9atV0.jpg)

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643361/how-to-load-json-dynamically-in-reactjs-component), but that method seems to cause react to hang indefinitely on the require statement.

Comment: you might want to give this a check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704755/how-to-read-xml-filedata-xml-in-react-js